# How do I correctly configure omniORB bootstrap for REDHAWK 1.9.0 on Fedora 20?

Tags: corba, redhawksdr, omniorb

I am attempting to port REDHAWK 1.9.0 to Fedora 20. I have been (so far as I can tell) successful at coercing everything into compiling. However, I am unable to get a domain to instantiate properly. After selecting a domain and device manager, I receive the message:

```
Failed to connect to domain: REDHAWK_DEV
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
```

OmniNames and OmniEvents are running happily, but REDHAWK isn't interfacing properly.

The console provides a little more info:

```
Jan 08, 2014 6:01:30 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.118.129; port: 900"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2200)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2221)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:223)

...and so forth
```

Since the error message concerns port 900, there seems to be some issue with the Java  bootstrapping function.

My cfg file is simple:

```
InitRef = NameService=corbaname::127.0.0.1:2809
InitRef = EventService=corbaloc::127.0.0.1:11169/omniEvents
endPoint = giop:tcp:127.0.0.1:
endPoint = giop:unix:
endPointPublish = all(addr)
supportBootstrapAgent=1
```

I have tried various permutations of bootstrapAgentHostname and
bootstrapAgentPort in the config file, and have disabled IPv6, but without luck.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong, or what configuration options I may be missing in the configuration file?

Comment: try `NameService=corbaloc::127.0.0.1:2809` and make sure a NamingService is running at port 2809 (omninames shall be there)